# Triggering single event from parent will trigger event in all reusable component in angular

Tags: angular, triggers, components

I am angular developer and currently I am developing complex application in angular.
In angular My project structure is look like below image :

[image]

I have one parent component and one child component.
I am passing some data into child component and process it into child and display it in the screen.
Now I want to change that data from parent component. I have found that way to call child function into parent function by make reference of child component into parent component using following way :

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent
```

And call function from it like this :

```
child.functionName();
```

But this code only call from first child only.

**Is there any way to call function from all child component at a time by single trigger from parent ?**

Please write here If any one have solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only fetching a single child. In it's place, you can use the QueryList to get all the children of single type. And then use it fire the event in the child in a loop.

For example:

```
@ContentChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

onButtonClick() {
  this.children.forEach((child: ChildComponent) => { child.functionName() });
}
```

Or going the Subject way:

ParentComponent

```
template: '<child [subject]="mySubject"></child>'

mySubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subkect<boolean>();

someButtonClick() {
  this.mySubject.emit(true);
}
```

Child Component

```
@Input() subject: Subject<boolean>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.subject.subscribe((value: boolean) => doSomething{});
}
```

Better to move the Subject to a service, which can be injected wherever required.

Comment: Thanks For Solution But I was found that solution. Is there any another solution or data flow  in which we need not to call function in loop. I needed only single trigger . Is it possible ?

Comment: Can We use Interface like concept for this scenario ?

Comment: What you are looking for might not be possible. but if you want to call only once, you can have a Subject in the parent component, and listen to it in the child. Then just do a subject.next(someVal) in the parent, and then all the children would receive the same.

Comment: OK, Let me try that.